# How to get value of attribute from meta tag?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get the value of `content=""` of the attribute from the meta tag from the WinHttpRequest ResponseText in the below HTML:

```
<meta name="nUrl" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
```

I've tried using `querySelectorAll` but it leads to object error.

```
extractedURL = html.querySelectorAll("meta[name='nUrl']").getAttribute("content")
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Did you try like this `html.querySelector("meta[name='nUrl']").getAttribute("content")`?

Comment: Yes, querySelector doesn’t work as well.

Comment: Then the content you look for are either dynamic or within an iframe and stuff.

Comment: it's not dynamic. It's as above <meta name="nUrl" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>. What i want is to get URL of the meta tag named nUrl.

Comment: Can you share the site url?

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question drop a comment and I will re-open.

Comment: Please ignore my earlier questions. Thanks QHarr. Managed to get it working now. Thank you too SIM.